# Print child process index when stdout is flushed

Tags: python, multiprocessing

My code runs a function (taken from an external library) on a number of child processes in parallel. This library function includes a simple progress bar, which prints and flushes to stdout from time to time. I would like to know which child process is printing every time flushing to stdout occurs. However, I would like to avoid changing anything related to the library function, because I don't want to have a private version of the library. Would this be possible?

Here is a typical example of what my code looks like:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import sys
from library import library_function

def my_function(parameter):
    # do some stuff
    do_stuff()
    # run library function
    library_function()
    return

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with mp.Pool() as pool:
         pool.map(my_function, parameters)

# library_function typically looks like
def library_function():
    for i in range(n):
        # do some things
        do_things()
        # print the iteration index
        print(f'iteration {i+1}/{n}')
        sys.stdout.flush()
    return
```

If I run the code as such, I won't know which child process is at which iteration. I would like the output to look like:

```
[Child 0] iteration 1/3
[Child 1] iteration 1/3
[Child 1] iteration 2/3
[Child 0] iteration 2/3
[Child 0] iteration 3/3
[Child 2] iteration 1/3
[Child 1] iteration 3/3
[Child 2] iteration 2/3
[Child 2] iteration 3/3
```

Comment: If `library_function` prints what it currently does in a loop. I don't see how could you could possibly get additional output on each line without modifying that code.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don't have an idea either, hence why I'm asking the question. But I don't want to modify the library function since it would mean having a private version of the library.

Comment: Well, if you are *willing* to modify the function, I've added an answer on how you might do it.

Comment: Thanks but that's exactly what I am trying not to do. Indeed the answer is pretty straightforward if I wanted to modify the library.

Comment: See my updated answer -- I think it' will do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will give you an idea:

```python
from contextlib import redirect_stdout
from io import StringIO
from multiprocessing import current_process

def my_function():
    f = StringIO()
    with redirect_stdout(f):
        library_function()
    s = f.getvalue()
    lines = s.splitlines()
    pid = current_process().pid
    for line in lines:
        print(f'[{pid}] {line}', flush=True)

def library_function():
    for i in range(4):
        print('This is line', i, flush=True)


my_function()
```

Prints:

```
[18492] This is line 0
[18492] This is line 1
[18492] This is line 2
[18492] This is line 3
```

If you don't want to use the process id, you can always pass to `my_function` an additional parameter, the *process_number* that varies from 1 .. N, where N is the number of child processes.

Comment: Great solution ! Thank you very much !

Comment: I don't know why I didn't think of this right away. Age, I suppose.